# How can I make a loop iteration wait for a user-triggered event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have a problem with the following code, the for loop contains 4 click events and I need for the loop to wait for the user to click on them and then move on with iteration, but when I run the code it just skips over the listeners. I have placed console.log satements inside my factory function to see what going on and I got this: factory was run 0
, factory was run 1

```js
//Array
let buttons = [];
let message = "Hi";
//creates a header with a questin and 
let factory = (message, index) => {
  let questionElement = document.createElement("h1");

  console.log(`factory was run ${index}`);
  //question holds a question that was send back
  text = message;

  //attaching text to questionElement
  questionElement.append(text);
  //return statement for header element
  return questionElement;
};

let hi = (event) => {
  console.log(`Hi from buttom ${event.data.button}`);
}

//Questions for loop
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

  //Factory function creates a header for the question
  let question = factory(message, i);

  console.log(question)

  //append question to the div container
  $("#main-container").append(question);

  //Loop that populates Buttons array
  for (let l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
    //Replaced JQuery with Vanilla
    buttons[l] = document.getElementById("btn" + l);
  }

  //for loop that sets button's inner
  //HTML's
  for (let s = 0; s < buttons.length; s++) {
    buttons[s].innerHTML = "Info";
  }

  //Button Listeners
  $("#btn0").click(hi, {
    button: "#btn0"
  });

  $("#btn1").click(hi, {
    button: "#btn1"
  });

  $("#btn2").click(hi, {
    button: "#btn2"
  });

  $("#btn3").click(hi, {
    button: "#btn3"
  });

}
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding event listeners. JavaScript will create the event listener and then move on. JavaScript will not pause the code and wait for an event to occur, unless you're using a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. You can't wait for an event inside a loop. Events are triggered asynchronously, and the listeners are executed when JavaScript is idle.

Comment: As @Promise stated, JS works top down and does not wait for code to be executed unless you prompt it to in your code, read up on [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and/or promise [.then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap this code into an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) (and then invoke the async function however is appropriate in your context), which would allow you to do the following:

```js
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  document.getElementById("btn0").addEventListner("click", (ev) => {
    hi();
    resolve();
  }, { once: true });
})
```

If you have to do four of these, instead of copying the above code four times and capturing the `hi` function in each one, you could make a producer helper function like so:

```js
function createClickPromise(btnId, hiCallback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    document.getElementById("btn0").addEventListner("click", (ev) => {
      hiCallback();
      resolve();
    }, { once: true });
  });
}
await createClickPromise("btn0", hi);
await createClickPromise("btn1", hi);
await createClickPromise("btn2", hi);
await createClickPromise("btn3", hi);
```